# Spark stand alone installation can't connect to master

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have Spark 2.3.1 running on my local windows 10 machine. I haven't tinkered around with any settings in the `spark-env` or `spark-defaults`. As I'm trying to connect to spark using `spark-shell`, I get a `failed to connect to master localhost:7077` warning. This is the entire error message, copied from the console :-

```
`C:\Users\abhi331\opt\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell
2019-02-04 22:38:36 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2019-02-04 22:38:45 WARN  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:87 - Failed to connect to master localhost:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        ... 11 more
2019-02-04 22:39:05 WARN  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:87 - Failed to connect to master localhost:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        ... 11 more
2019-02-04 22:39:25 WARN  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:87 - Failed to connect to master localhost:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        ... 11 more
2019-02-04 22:39:44 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend:70 - Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
2019-02-04 22:39:44 WARN  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:66 - Application ID is not initialized yet.
2019-02-04 22:39:44 WARN  StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint:66 - Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
2019-02-04 22:39:45 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:515)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:924)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:103)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:110)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:515)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:933)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:924)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:924)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:103)
  ... 55 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql`
```

I'm running Scala version 2.11.8 and Java 1.8.0_181, and haven't been able to connect to `localhost:8080` either. Can someone please help me fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick checklist. Did you check:

- Run the master with start-master?

  - Is the master running?
  - Can you telnet to port 7077, e.g. `telnet localhost 7077`?
- Run a slave with start-slave pointing to the master?

  - Is the slave running?
- Once all is running, can you connect to port 8080 via your browser?

Comment: I tried running `start-master.sh`. It opened another terminal where the first line said 'hostname : unknown option --f'' and 'unknown option --o', the 2nd line repeated a bunch of times.
- `telnet localhost 7077` gives me `Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7077: Connect failed` . I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, given I could connect to Spark without any issues just this weekend.
- I also ran `start-workers.sh`, but I am still unable to connect to `Spark` or `8080`

Answer (score 0):

*Spark-shell* starts a Spark master and Spark workers which will connect to the master. By default, workers try to connect to the master on address `localhost:7077` but in your case, they couldn't find the master on localhost!

---

Suppose your current IP is `10.10.20.3`, you can introduce it to SPARK by:

Just add the following line to the file `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.cmd`:

```
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.10.20.3
```

Or add the Variable `SPARK_MASTER_HOST` with the value of `10.10.20.3` to the *Windows Environment Variables* and reboot the system.

Or as a temporary solution, you can set *SPARK_MASTER_HOST* variable in cmd and the run spark-shell:

```
set SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.10.20.3
C:\Users\abhi331\opt\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell
```

Comment: I tried adding the `set SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.10.20.3` but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you change the IP `10.10.20.3` to your machine IP? Did you try all three solutions?

Comment: I did. I swapped out the IP you mentioned with my machine IP. I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score -2):

First spark is not meant to be installed on windows, and next if you do so, if i am not wrong you need to install some unethical software that makes spark to believe it is running on linux and connected to hadoop.